# Which are the best practices for data intensive reading and writing in a HD?

Tags: c++, c, performance, io, disk

I'm developing a C++ application (running in a Linux box) that is very intensive in reading log files and writing derived results in disk. I'd like to know which are the best practices for optimizing these kind of applications:

- Which OS tweaks improve performance?
- Which programming patterns boost IO throughput?
- Is pre-processing the data (convert to binary, compress data, etc...) a helpful measure?
- Does chunking/buffering data helps in performance?
- Which hardware capabilities should I be aware of?
- Which practices are best for profiling and measuring performance in these applications?
- (express here the concern I'm missing)

Is there a good read where I could get the basics of this so I could adapt the existing know-how to my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Keep data in buffers and write as less as possible, it's so slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compression may certainly help a lot and is much simpler than tweaking the OS. Check out the `gzip` and `bzip2` support in the [Boost.IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library. This takes its toll on the processor, though.

Measuring these kinds of jobs starts with the `time` command. If system time is very high compared to user time, then your program spends a lot of time doing system calls. If wall-clock ("real") time is high compared to system and user time, it's waiting for the disk or the network. The `top` command showing significantly less than 100% CPU usage for the program is also a sign of I/O bottleneck.

Comment: We get around 3 times speedup by duing `zcat bigfile.gz | ourprogram` vs `ourprorogram < bigfile` . At the cost of higher CPU usage of both zcat doing the decompression, ourprogram not blocking on IO, and the initial gzipping of the big (10Gb) files. bzip2 gives us less performance than zcat - probably due to decompression spending more time - but that all depends on how much CPU time you spend vs the decompression.

Answer (score 3):

1) Check out your disk's sector size.
2) Make sure the disk is defragged.
3) Read data that is "local" to the last reads you have done to improve cache locality (Cacheing is performend by the operating system and many hard drives also have a built-in cache).
4) Write data contiguously.

For write performance, Cache blocks of data in memory until you reach a multiple of the sector size then initiate an asynchronous write to disk.  Do not overwrite the data currently being written until you can be definite the data has been written (ie sync the write).  Double or triple buffering can help here.

For best read performance you can double buffer reads.  So lets say you cache 16K blocks on read.  Read the 1st 16K from disk into block 1.  Initiate an asynchronous read of the 2nd  16K into block 2.  Start working on block 1.  When you have finished with block 1 sync the read of block 2 and start an async read into block 1 of the 3rd 16K block into block 1.  Now work on block 2. When finished sync the read of the 3rd 16K block, initiate an async read of the 4th 16K into block 2 and work on block 1.  Rinse and repeat until you have processed all the data.

As already stated the less data you have to read the less time will be lost to reading from disk so it may well be worth reading compressed data and spending the CPU time expanding each block on read.  Equally compressing the block before write will save you disk time.  Whether this is a win or not really will depend on how CPU intensive your processing of the data is.

Also if the processing on the blocks is asymmetric (ie processing block 1 can take 3 times as long as processing block 2) then consider triple or more buffering for reads.

Answer (score 2):

Get information about the volume you'll be writing to/reading from and create buffers that match the characteristics of the volume. e.g. 10 * clusterSize.

Buffering helps a lot, as would minimizing the amount of writing you have to do.

Answer (score 2):

As it was stated here, you should check size of block. You do this with stat family functions.
In struct stat this information is located in field st_blksize.

Second thing is function posix_fadvise(), which gives advice to OS about paging. You tell system how you're going to use file (or even fragment of a file). You'll find more on manual page.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, use CreateFile() with  FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN and/or FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING rather than fopen() - at least for writing this returns immediately rather than waiting for the data to flush to disk